# Error Log information in VB Script while processing

Tags: asp.net, vbscript, error-handling

I am having an VBScript files which runs by many instance of jobs. I need to log the error information if any error occurs in the script processing. If i maintain a log file then how can i differentiate the log file for each instances (around 10 simultaneous instances) of vb script calling.

I dont go for any db logging.

Please suggest some good ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use the same log file for all instances.  I would then have each instance create a GUID:

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/resources/qanda/feb05/hey0221.mspx

When an error is logged by an instance, it uses the GUID to identify itself.  This way it shouldn't matter if you have 10 or 50 instances, they will be unique in logging and you won't have a ton of log files everywhere.